# Printing with White pla, problems while printing a benchy boat

Tags: pla, print-failure

So I am having trouble with this white pla, I am currently printing with a tempature of 225 degrees and going lower worsen the printing, but what I find strange is that it is always the same area that screws up.

I am using a Prusa MK3S, and printing with this fillament: https://shop.prusa3d.com/en/filament/39-white-pla-filament-1kg.html

[image]

EDIT:

NEW INFORMATION, this only happens with my white pla. I have a Silver one, and it prints it perfectly.

Secound white print, see that silver pla is totally fine.

[image]

Comment: probably a problem with the Gcode. Try with a different file.

Comment: Do other models have problems at this same height? Have you re-sliced and tried the new gcode?

Comment: the underextrusion is at the end of the bow height...

Comment: @Davo Only my white pla fails, I can print it fine with the Silver filament I have.

Comment: @AvishkaKavinduB.Dambawinna It works fine, when I print the same fillament with another color. In this example Silver Pla.

Comment: Has this only failed once, or does it fail in the same place repeatedly - but only with white PLA?

Comment: @Davo Around the same place, only with with pla. I will put up a new image.

Answer (score 1):

Even from the same manufacturer different colors of filament have (slightly) different properties requiring different settings of your slicer.
But here it seems you have some underextrusion at this hight. Have you tried again the same file with the same filament and the same settings? It could be a fault in the white filament at that spot that (temporarily) clogged your nozzle.

Comment: Have made 3 prints of the same boat, sadly fails at the same area but only with the white pla.